# Button (new onClickListener()) showing grey

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener

I have a button in a constraintLayout and "(new onClickListener())" is showing grey and button is not working

```
findViewById (R.id.button_test).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

this is xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".RecipeListActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button_test"
        android:text="test"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: can you please show your all code in activity

Answer (score 2):

First declare your button and then set the `OnClickListener`, like this:

```java
yourButton = findViewById (R.id.button_test);
yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onClick(View v) { 
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    } 
});
```

---

Edit:

In Java8, lambda expressions were introduced. This replaced a lot of redundant calls, like when implementing `setOnClickListener`. The grey you see is an indication that the method can be simplified by doing the following:

Click on the grey area and then press `alt`+`Enter` to convert your `OnClickListener` to a lambda expression:

```java
yourButton.setOnClickListener(v -> Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); )
```

Comment: hmmm, that's weird. try casting the `findViewById(R.id.button_test);` to type button and see if that works

Comment: Show your entire `onCreate`/`OnClickListener`

Comment: there is only this button in onCreate